# How to avoid parameter values cache in SQL Server Reporting services Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SQL Server report keeps parameter values in cache. I am populating parameter values from database. If we reopen the report, the same parameter values are listed even if there is change in parameter values in database. Can we avoid this behavior?
I am using WebForms version of ReportViewer control to view reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added <%@ OutputCache Location="None"%> on the page where ReportViewer control is and it works.